# TEXTAREA - update function - php - doesn't get text value from database

Tags: php, mysql, crud

So I've developed a small web application using php and mysql, and in the registration form of (patients) I've made some input type texts which work really fine when i call them for update they display in the forms. But the Detajet Field is not exporting to the field from database.

code for the form:

```
<textarea type="text"
 name="detajet" 
value="<?= $detajet; ?>"
  class="form-control"
 placeholder="Detajet" 
rows="8"></textarea>
```

PHP CODE:

```
if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
        $id=$_GET['edit'];


    $query="SELECT * FROM crud WHERE id=?";
            $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result=$stmt->get_result();
            $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
    
            $id=$row['id'];
            $name=$row['name'];
            $mosha=$row['mosha'];
            $phone=$row['phone'];
            $sherbimi=$row['sherbimi'];
            $pagesa=$row['pagesa'];
            $detajet=$row['detajet'];
            $photo=$row['photo'];
    
            $update=true;
        }
```

I need help to get textarea variable to export it in the forms for the update.

I've tried the same method as: <input type="text"

But this form has to be multiline is input type text is only single line but I need to write longer paragraph for the detajet field so that's the reason i used textarea and not text.

Image:[image: screenshot of image of the textarea which is not displaying when i call it]

Comment: Can you share a complete code of your web app so we can answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For value in textarea, it should be enclosed between `<textarea .... >` and `</textarea>`

Hence change

```
<textarea type="text" name="detajet" value="<?= $detajet; ?>"
  class="form-control" placeholder="Detajet" 
rows="8"></textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea type="text" name="detajet"
  class="form-control" placeholder="Detajet" 
rows="8"><?php echo $detajet; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Ken Lee, that was the problem, Thank you very much, its working now <3